# Deleting legend entries on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, legend

In QGIS I have deleted features from the attribute table and the map but the labels still remain in the legend.

How can I remove them?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

In the Print Composer select the legend.  Then look for the legend in the item properties (right side pane).  Select the legend item you want to remove. Hit the subtraction sign icon.